# How to replace NaN with Jinja default filter?

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, nan

I am trying to use the [`default` filter in Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#default) to replace missing values with default values.

It turns out that my data source has some NaNs, not just missing values.
For my use case, I want to replace NaNs with a default value.
But the `default` filter just passes `NaN` through without substitution.

Are there any filters in Jinja2 which would allow me to replace NaN values with something else, easily? (Of course I could write a custom filter, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution.)

For context, I'm doing this from Ansible, which has [a few more filters available than plain Jinja2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

## MWE

`playbook.yaml`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: generate cloudformation template
    template:
      src: input.j2
      dest: output.txt
    vars:
      data:
        - value: 123
          comment: this is an integer
        - value: None
          comment: This is None
        - value: NaN
          comment: This is NaN
        - comment: this is missing
        - value: ''
          comment: empty string
```

`input.j2`

```
{% for row in data %}
{{ row['comment'] }}
{{ row['value'] | default('default') }}
{{ row['value'] | default('default', boolean=True) }}

{% endfor %}
```

Run with:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
cat output.txt
```

## Actual behavior

```
this is an integer
123
123
123

This is None
None
None
default

This is NaN
NaN
default
default

this is missing
default
default
default

empty string

default
default
```

### Desired behavior

```
...

This is NaN
NaN
default
default

...
```

(It would be good to also have a solution that replaces `None`s. I'm not sure why `None | default('x', boolean=True)` doesn't do that, since `None` is falsey.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default* filter won't help you here. A custom filter might be a good idea to simplify the code. But, you can convert the data also using current filters.

For example, add the default value first if the attribute is missing

```yaml
_data_default:
  - value: default
_data: "{{ _data_default|product(data)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

```yaml
_data:
  - comment: this is an integer
    value: 123
  - comment: This is None
    value: None
  - comment: This is NaN
    value: NaN
  - comment: this is missing
    value: default
  - comment: empty string
    value: ''
```

Replace the values

```yaml
_regex: '^NaN|None|null$'
_regex_empty: '^$'
_replace: default
_data_values: "{{ _data|map(attribute='value')|
                  map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|
                  map('regex_replace', _regex_empty, _replace)|
                  map('community.general.dict_kv', 'value')|list }}"
```

```yaml
_data_values:
  - value: '123'
  - value: default
  - value: default
  - value: default
  - value: default
```

and combine the items of the lists

```yaml
data2: "{{ data|zip(_data_values)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

```yaml
data2:
  - comment: this is an integer
    value: '123'
  - comment: This is None
    value: default
  - comment: This is NaN
    value: default
  - comment: this is missing
    value: default
  - comment: empty string
    value: default
```

Fit the options to your needs and put the variables as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).